Nginx の デフォルトuserはセキュリティを考えると変更したほうがよいか？
Nginx の デフォルトuserはセキュリティを考えると変更したほうがよいですか？
質問経緯
Debian 12 にNginxをインストールしたら user が www-data に設定されていました。
そこで初めて、userは nginxでなくてもよいことに気が付きました。

web server daemon (apache httpd / nginx など) の実効ユーザーは、一般ユーザーなり root なりにしないほうが良いとされています。
理由： server daemon の脆弱性を突かれた場合に、攻撃者が得られる権限が server daemon の実効ユーザーの権限になるからです。なので「故意に権限を減らしたユーザーを作って、それを実効ユーザーに指定する」ことで、侵入に成功した攻撃者が得られる権限が小さくなる≒被害が少なくなるわけです。
権限が少なければそのユーザー名は何でもよい、すなわち www でも nginx でも www-data nobody httpd なんでも良いわけです。なのであなたの好きにユーザー名を付けでも一向にかまいません。もちろんデフォルトユーザー名である www-data でも構いません。
ユーザー名がデフォルトのままだと、仮にそのデフォルト名が攻撃者に知られたならば web server の OS が Ubuntu か Debian か CentOS か RHEL か・・・云々を知る手掛かりになりえる、という点で「変更したほうが良い」という意見もあります。逆に知られてしまってもリスクは変わらないという意見もあります。あと教本とか Web 記事とかを見ながらいろいろやってみたい、という場合に「自分がユーザー名を変更したことを忘れて記事通りに写経する」とうまくいかなくなることもあります。
web server を The Internet に公開して全世界の攻撃者からアタックされるのか
web server を LAN 内に公開するだけで勉強目的に使うのか
変更したことを常に意識し解説記事を読む・試行する際に適切な修正が脳内でできる自信があるか
あたりで決めてしまえばよいでしょう。
web server daemon 専用ユーザーを初心管理者がテキトーに作ると、権限を与えすぎたり足らなかったりします＝デフォルトユーザー名を使うより悪い結果になるので、オイラなら変更しないことをお勧めします。

なるほど。ユーザー名うんぬんよりも、「故意に権限を減らしたユーザーを作成して、それを実効ユーザーに指定する」ことが大事なのですね。「web server daemon 専用ユーザーを初心管理者がテキトーに作ると、権限を与えすぎたり足らなかったりします＝デフォルトユーザー名を使うより悪い結果になるので、変更しないことをお勧めします」アドバイスありがとうございました。
